# Rails 3 Create method using nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, has-many, form-for

How can I clean this up using rails 3 features? I have a post that belongs to a group and also a user. The group and user has_many posts. I am using a nested resource

```
resources :groups do
    resources :posts
end



<%= form_for @post, :url => group_posts_path(params[:group_id]) do |f| %>
....
<% end %>

 def create
   @group = Group.find(1)
   @post = @group.posts.build(params[:post])
   @post.user_id = current_user.id

   respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
      .....
      end
   end
 end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method in your model.

If you're not familiar with nested forms check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [the second part](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

In view:

```
  <%= form_for [@group, @group.posts.build] do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

In controller:

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :find_group
    ...
    def create
      @post = @group.posts.build(params[:post])
      current_user.posts << @post
    end

    protected
    def find_group
      @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    end
  end
```